# Modal closing when using Flatlist scrollView in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-modal library, but when....

I am trying to implement flatlist inside swipe down Modal... (For country code picker), But when I scroll Flatlist then my modal is swiping down and closing. So, please suggest how I can manage two scrolls at the same time...

I want a smooth scroll experience inside a Modal, but right now it's closing a Modal when I scroll Flatlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your problem this is a simple issue you just have to enable:

```
propagateSwipe={true}
```

inside the modal. you can have conditional code for this to be true or false on the onPressIn() & onPressOut functions when you press on the flatlist.